# Array modifier fit curve option( curve direction problem(already Ctrl+A applied, but failed to fix)

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I'm trying to wall model following a path curve, 
so used array modifier, and used 'Fit curve' option

problem is

the wall model does not follow the curve path while duplicating the wall object like the first image(below)

I applied scale and rotation (Ctrl +a) and the T panel's number seems not wrong.[image]
and I checked the origin of the object and curve several times.
But I couldn't find the clue at all.

How can I fix this problem?

Thank you for your time and help in advance;

[image]

Here is my blend file
[image]

Comment: Hello. Let me just adress how well is this question written. Clear subject, with images, added tags and a blendfile attached. And a *thank you in advance*? I'd upvote this more times just for these things. Bra-vo!

Comment: the Array modifier with the Fit Curve won't make the object follow the curve, it will just adjust the amount of duplications so that the total length of the object is as long as the curve. To make the object follow the curve you need a Curve modifier as explained by Jachym Michal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works better when you use the *Curve modifier*.

1) Go to *Edit mode* and rotate your mesh 90 degrees so it aligns better with the curve.
2) Set array modifier to *Count* or *Length*
3) Add a *Curve Modifier* and set the target to your curve.

*Rotate your mesh in edit mode.*
[image]

*Set Array modifier to Count and add a Curve modifier*
[image]

*Voilà!*

And here is the edited file.
[image]

Comment: I really appreciated :) Thank you for your detailed and kind explanation, it is truly helpful.

Comment: Happy to help :). You can now mark the question as answered, for others with a similar problem.